# Receiving an error upon heroku login not sure why permission seems to be the issue

Tags: git, heroku, terminal

I keep getting this error but if I do sudo heroku login it works... How do I fix this, I even tried to do ssh generate but it works with sudo only too...

```
The-MacBook-Pro:prod lior$ heroku login
 !    Error reading /Users/lior/.netrc
 !    Permission denied - /Users/lior/.netrc
 !    You may need to delete this file and run `heroku login` to recreate it.
```

Comment: ok well I showed the hidden files deleted the .netrc files and that worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `heroku login` command, it will write your Heroku API key to the `.netrc` file.

If you first run `sudo heroku login`, then the `.netrc` file will be owned by the root account and not your user account.  Unless you change permissions on the file using `chmod a+x ~/.netrc` or change ownership with `sudo chown lior ~/.netrc` then you wont be able to read or write to the `~/.netrc` file.

Deleting the `~/.netrc` file and running `heroku login` is another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Confirmed that deleting .netrc file solved it for me.